# Add Looped Variable Values

Tags: python

I'm taking a python course and there is a question that requires adding a user's input.

The question is:

> Sometimes a programmer does not know how many times data is to be
> entered. For example, suppose you want to create a program that adds
> an unspecified amount of positive numbers entered by the user. The
> program stops adding numbers when the user enters a zero or a negative
> number. Then the program prints the total. Before creating this
> program, review the three actions required for all loops:
>
> a. Initialize a variable that will be used in the test condition: What
> will be tested to determine if the loop is executed or not? Write a
> line of code that initializes a variable to be used in the test
> condition of the loop for this program. The variable should contain a
> value entered by the user.
>
> b. Include a test condition that causes the loop to end when the
> condition is false: What is the test condition for the while loop used
> in this program?
>
> c. Within the loop body, update the variable used in the test
> condition: Write the code for the loop body. Include the code to
> update the variable in the test condition.
>
> d. Complete the program. Enter and execute the code. Does it work
> properly?

The code I have is:

```
while True:
  a = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))
  total = a + a
  if a>0:
    a+a

  else:
    print("The number you entered is a negative number or 0 \n The sum is: ", total)
    break
```

The program doesn't add all the values the user entered, how do I fix this?

Comment: `a+a` creates a new object. Then, you don't do anything with that object, and it is discarded immediately

Comment: `total = a + a` should be `total += a`

Comment: Try to think about the problem logically. 1) what should happen *first*: deciding whether the number is valid, or adding it to the total? Therefore, how should that code be ordered? 2) Should the number be added to the total if it is not valid? Therefore, should the code to add the number be somewhere inside the `if`/`else` structure, or somewhere outside? If it should be inside, should it be in the `if`, or in the `else`? Why? 3) What should the code look like to add to the total? (Hint: what should be added together? Then, what should be done with the sum?)

Comment: 4) Is anything else missing? (Hint: what should the `total` be if no valid numbers are provided? Does `total` need to exist first, in order to add to it? Can you think of a simple way to address these two problems, for example by setting an initial value for the `total` variable? Where in the code should that go - before, inside or after the `while` loop? Why? (Hint: how many times should it happen? Should it happen before, or after trying to add numbers to the total?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test for the end of the loop before using the input in a calculation. Then you don't break out of the loop, add the input to the total variable, not to itself.

```
total = 0
while True:
    a = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))
    if a <= 0:
        print("The number you entered is a negative number or 0 \n The sum is: ", total)
        break   
    total += a
```

Answer (score 1):

Your on the right track, but your code needs some tweaking.

Breaking your code down:

```
while True: 
    a = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))
```

This is fine so far. Your creating a loop, getting user input, casting to an integer value and saving in a variable named `a`

```
    total = a+a
```

This is where some issues appear. What's happening is you are adding `a` and `a` together, basically doubling the user's input value and saving that as the total.

To keep a running total you want to add the user input to whatever the value of `total` is.

Like this:

```
    total = total + a # longway
    # or
    total += a # shorthand way (preferable)
```

You will also need to move `total += a` into your condition statement.

```
    if a>0:
        total+=0
    else:
        # ~~ Do Stuff ~~~
```

Doing this will allow your condition to check if the user's input is positive before adding it to the total. However, you'll notice moving total inside the condition results in a `NameError: name 'total' is not defined error`.

To resolve this issue you need to declare `total` outside of the loop. If you were to declare `total` inside the loop, the value would be reset every iteration of the loop. In the case of `total += a`, your trying to add a value to an unitialized variable.

Your final code would look like this:

```
# Initialize total
total = 0

# Get and sum user input
while True:
    a = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))
    if a > 0:
        total += a
    else:
        print("The number you entered is a negative number or 0 \n The sum is: ", total)
        break
```

To clean it up a bit, you can also check if you should exit the loop before adding the user input to the total.

The resulting code:

```
# Initialize total
total = 0

# Get and sum user input
while True:
    a = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))
    if a <= 0:
        print("The number you entered is a negative number or 0 \n The sum is: ", total)
        break
    total += a
```

You can expand on this further. For instance you can move the user input into a function and call that function within the loop. You'll notice if you enter a non-integer value your code breaks. You can add code to your function which validates user input is an integer.

resulting code:

```
# Initialize total
total = 0

# Function to get and validate input
def get_input():
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input("Enter a number: "))
            return user_input
        except ValueError:
            print("That was not a number, try again.")

# Get and sum user input
while True:
    a = get_input()
    if a <= 0:
        print("The number you entered is a negative number or 0 \n The sum is: ", total)
        break
    total += a
```